# Are there any sources other than Acts 2 reporting Xenoglossy during the first centuries of Christianity?

Tags: church-history, early-church, acts, extra-biblical, speaking-in-tongues

[Xenoglossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenoglossy), the ability to suddenly speak a language one has never learned or studied, is reported to have taken place at Pentecost in Acts chapter 2. Are there any other independent sources that claim something similar to have happened during the early stages of Christianity? Any other reports of xenoglossy apart from Acts 2 during, say, the first 300 years of Church history?

Note: there is a similar question [Is there any extra-biblical evidence of tongues from the first, or even second, century?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/57350/50422), but the question itself and its single answer so far appear to be focused on glossolalia, not xenoglossy.

---

Similar question constrained to modern times: [Are there any documented cases of Xenoglossy (i.e. "Acts 2:1-13 type" tongues, understood by a foreigner) in recent history (19th century on)?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/80486/50422)

Comment: Are you discounting Acts 10:46 and Acts 19:6. And if so, why ?

Comment: In those cases it is not explicitly stated that they spoke in foreign languages, but even if they did, I'm not sure to what extent you can consider different chapters of a same book "independent sources".